# TRYING TO JOIN THESE TABLES but getting Error Code: 1052. Column 'Flight_no' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am trying to join two tables but getting the "Error Code: 1052. Column 'Flight_no' in field list is ambiguous". Can someone please help me?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Flight_no, Airline_code. Lname, Passenger_id
FROM Ticketinfo JOIN  Flights
ON Ticketinfo.Flight_no = Flights.Flight_no;
```

Here is info on my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Flights
(
  Flight_no INT NOT NULL,
  Airline_code char (5) NULL,
  Departure_AirportCode char (5) NOT NULL,
  Departure_date date NOT NULL,
  Arrival_AirportCode char (5) Not NULL,
  Arrival_date date not null,
  Price  decimal (5,2),
  Airline_no INT NOT NULL,
  Route_no varchar (8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Flight_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (Airline_no) REFERENCES Airlines(Airline_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (Route_no) REFERENCES Routes(Route_no)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE TicketInfo
(
  Confirmation_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
  Lname varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Passenger_id varchar (6) NOT NULL,
  Fare_type varchar (3) NOT NULL,
  Flight_no INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Confirmation_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (Passenger_id) REFERENCES Passenger(Passenger_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Flight_no) REFERENCES Flights(Flight_no)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous. Flight_No is in both tables.

Prefix a specific table to the field like this:

```
SELECT Flights.Flight_no, Airline_code. Lname, Passenger_id
FROM Ticketinfo JOIN  Flights
ON Ticketinfo.Flight_no = Flights.Flight_no;
```

Comment: Thanks @ Chizzie - Question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Flight_no` column appears in both tables, you need to resolve the ambiguity in the SELECT by specifying which table you want the `Flight_no` column to come from. Since, by virtue of your join, the value is the same in both tables, it really doesn't matter which you choose.

```
SELECT Ticketinfo.Flight_no, Airline_code. Lname, Passenger_id
FROM Ticketinfo JOIN  Flights
ON Ticketinfo.Flight_no = Flights.Flight_no;
```

Comment: hey Joe - thanks for the quick response. I did see from a different post that this might be the problem. So I went and modified my code but now I get: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Airline_code.Lname' in 'field list'

Comment: Nvm Joe it worked now! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qualify *all* column references with either the table name or (my preference) a short table alias.  For example:

```
SELECT f.flight_no
     , f.airline_code
     , t.lname
     , t.passenger_id
  FROM Ticketinfo t
  JOIN Flights f
    ON f.flight_no = t.flight_no
```

Beyond resolving "ambiguous column" errors, and preventing a working statement from breaking when new columns are added to tables... this also aids future human readers. If a column reference isn't qualified, the reader doesn't know which table that column is in, not without going and looking up the table definitions.

Later, when a column named `lname` is added to the `Flights` table, the query won't throw an "ambiguous column" error. That's why we qualify *all* column references.

Comment: @ Spencer...Many thanks! That worked. I am new to this and have been trying to resolve it without knowing what to look for. Thanks also for the explanation. I have save yours and Joe's  to my little cheat sheet.